# "Source property was not set before writing to the event log."

Tags: event-log

One user of a Application is getting the Error "Source property was not set before writing to the event log."  when the user uploads a file. Other users of the same application are not getting this Error when they upload a file. What could be the possible reasons?

Comment: I think that user's flux capacitor needs an upgrade... and possibly, they're wearing the wrong flavor of jeggings... I'm sorry, what were we talking about. "Application" is, to be blunt, rather nebulous. Is it a paper "Application"? Is there an OS involved? Does it have a name... or is that a "secret"? Here's my best guess, based on what details you have provided: The user's "source property" was not set before the "Application" attempted to write to the event log. There, that should help you out, no?

Comment: There is a Internal Website that the users use to upload files. It works for all users except 1 user.

Comment: Was it developed internally? Do you have access to the developers? I would suggest that it's a local configuration issue, i.e. the way this particular user has been set up?

Comment: Yes, I can upload s a file. I dont get this Error. But when she tries to use the same website she is getting an Error. Other users in the same organization is not getting the Error. Feel totally confused.

Comment: How can I check her Configuration Settings?

Comment: Is `service.msi` involved? Is the service halting on her machine? Are there any .DLL's needed to make you application work?

Comment: I will check into this and tell you. Thanks.

Comment: There are no DLL's or No Service.msi.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing your application on Dotnet Framkework-
Are you creating a event Source  as below in your code.

VBCode

```
EventLog.CreateEventSource("ApplicationError","MyApp")
```

Answer (score 0):

Running the application as an administrator user fixed this issue for me. The user that was running the application did not have rights to write to the error log.